# Python tools for Visual Studio - no option for version 3.6

Tags: visual-studio-2015, python-3.6

I'm working on a new python project in Visual Studio and can't seem to get a 100% accurate python environment in Visual Studio configured.

The python environment window doesn't seem to find any existing python environments (I expected to see my python & anaconda installs as options), first of all. Weird, but whatever - I figure I'll use the config options to add one.

Thing is - the python versions I can choose from only go between 2.5 and 3.5. No 3.6. What gives? Is 3.6 not supported in my current setup?

My python version is 3.6 64-bit, VS version is 2015 community (version 14.0.25431.01, update 3). I have python tools for Visual Studio version 2.2.6 installed.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer in the release notes of the github page [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/releases/v2.2.6). "Note that Python 3.6 is still not supported by this release. This fix merely prevents a crash when unsupported versions are configured as custom environments." I seem to be getting on ok using my custom environment on version 3.6 with 3.5 selected during config. So far anyway.